# Drag and drop on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have a webpage that features jQuery drag and drop. It works on all desktop browsers but not on iPads. Somehow the `click + drag` event is captured to move the page up and down.

So, how is drag-and-drop generally done on iPads without writing iPad apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't** use the mouse events ... you need to change to **touch events**

> http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/

One way is to divide both code using a mobile Framework, like jQTouch, jQMobile, etc...

Here is a [simple test](http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/?/iphone/touch) using jQTouch

---

## Just added a simple test of my own

using **jQuery UI Sortable** for both **Browser** and **iPad**

> http://jsbin.com/ujeyac/19/

using [jQuery UI Sortable demo code](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) and the [Touch Events](http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/) code, **works great!**