# iPad takes three touch for JavaScript click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I have problem with iPad. I use 3 function in JavaScript for anchor tag, `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, `onclick`.

But when I test it on the iPad then for first touch it trigger `onmouseover`, and then it takes two another touch for execute `onclick` event.

That means it take total three touch for click event. Generally it has to take only two touch for it. Why is it so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fully support Mobile devices with their Touch Screens you **can't use the mouse events**... you need to change to **touch events**

http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/

Another way is to divide the code using a mobile Framework, like [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/), [jQMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), etc...

They support Mouse Events and Touch Events right out of the box.

After you make your code support for Touch Events, **even Drag and Drop will work nicely**

> [Drag and drop on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503983/drag-and-drop-on-ipad/7504212#7504212)

Comment: I have removed hover event from javascript so it works fine for me. Just 1 touch to activate link. Thank you all

Comment: The link is dead. Can someone tell me how to add event listeners for iOS devices?

Comment: @KalC if you follow the 2nd link you get to another answer where I have a working example.