# Change event not firing on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, onchange

I have this page working on every browser in the world (firefox, safari, chrome, opera, maybe my microwave menu too)... On ipad the event change seems not to be fired...
What i'm trying to do is calculate the bmi field and filling it with the calculated values, qhich depends by the value of "altezza" and "peso".
I'm using jquery mobile, which also seem to have a little crash on this page, for when i select the text field for "peso" the footer remains stuck at the middle of the page instead of being at the end of the page. 
No javascript, or php error are thrown. I am using firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("div:jqmData(role='page'):last").bind('pageinit', function(){
var altezza;
var peso;
// CALCOLO BMI
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
}
function calcolaBmi(){
    var altezzaBMI=$("#altezza").val();
    var pesoBMI=$("#peso").val();

    if(altezzaBMI!="" || pesoBMI!=""){
        alert("calcolo"+$("#peso").val());
    }
    if(altezzaBMI=="" || pesoBMI==""){
        $("#bmi").val("");
    }else{
        altezzaBMI=parseFloat($("#altezza").val());
        pesoBMI=parseFloat($("#peso").val());
        bmi=pesoBMI/(Math.pow(altezzaBMI/100,2));
        $("#bmi").val(roundNumber(bmi,2));
        alert("Altezza:"+altezzaBMI+" Peso:"+pesoBMI+" "+bmi);          
    }
}

$("input[name=altezza]").change(function () {
    calcolaBmi();
});
$("input[name=peso]").change(function () {
    calcolaBmi();
});
}
</script> 


<div data-role="content"> 
 <form action="#" id="Scheda2Form" class="validate">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">  
  <label for="altezza">1. Altezza (in centimetri):</label>
  <input type="text" name="altezza" id="altezza" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" value="" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
  <label for="peso">Peso (in chilogrammi):</label>
  <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"  value="" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
  <label for="bmi">BMI:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bmi" id="bmi" value=""/>
  </div>
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: you can't use key events to work on a touch device, you need either to use touch events or make sure when the page load, you attach the correct one... see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7504212/28004

Comment: I saw that updating the iOS to 6 it began working, but when the javascript function is being executed the footer of the jquery mobile page moves to the middle of the page and remain there... I'll try with touch events...